# SMTP Error Issue - PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, mail-server

I have a daily newsletter I send out to a list of people each day. I use PHP and the PHPMailer object to send the emails.

This has been working fine up until today when I didn't get an email (test) and I checked the logs to find that intermittently I was getting SMTP errors back from

```
mail->Send();
```

Method of the class on SOME of the people - not all of them.

All of the emails were exactly the same size (length in characters) apart from their name and email address.

The error details from

```
$mail->ErrorInfo;
```

Included these two errors

SMTP Error: Data not accepted.<p>SMTP server error: 2.1.5 Ok

SMTP Error: Data not accepted.<p&gtSMTP server error: </p>

Why there are broken P tags in the error message I have no idea - also why the first error has OK in it??

However other people in the loop had emails go out fine.

Also when I put the script into test mode so ONLY these failures were emailed out (so one call of the script = one email to one person), I found no problem and the people got their emaail.

Now I asked tech support what the error meant and got back "Google it" and I can't find the error 2.1.5 OK anywhere. I don't really get why it says OK after an error either.

As a test for tomorrow I put a test in for a failed Send and then a Sleep for 5 seconds with a retry.

I don't know if this will help but I thought that maybe my SMTP server which is on the same server as my script (Rackspace VPS Linux) was having temporary issues connecting so a sleep might be handy in this situation.

This is the first time I have had this issue, I haven't rebooted APACHE or my server (or mailserver) and before this script I had another one send out 403 emails without any problem.

It would be nice to know what the error is and why it happened though.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

That error is defined exactly where you would expect it to be - in [the RFC that defines SMTP error codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463). 2.1.5 means "Destination address valid". That it starts with a 2 means it's not an error as such, but a response code - warnings and errors start with 4 and 5. Why you got it, I don't know, but it certainly seems it was not expected in that context. Mail servers often have problems - they run out of disk space, get swamped by spam filtering, and this is why mail servers have queues. Sending directly using PHPMailer's SMTP class is not appropriate for high-volume sending - using SMTP is fine, but point it at a proper (nearby) MTA that can handle deliveries properly.

As for the garbled `ErrorInfo` content, I suspect you are using an old version of PHPMailer - the debug output has been cleaned up fairly recently. Another thing that changed lately is the handling of errors during single sends to multiple recipients (e.g. BCCs) - it's now much more likely to get to the end of a long recipient list without giving up than it was before.

Comment: So would a sleep between message retries help if the error is not really an error. The page of response codes I was looking at didn't show 2.1.5 so I didn't see any mention of it. IF 2 means "Destination address valid" then what does the .1 and .5 mean? Is there anyway to find out. Could it just be a case of a swamped mail server? And in that case would longer timeouts between each email send and retry help?

Comment: That it starts with a `2` means that it's a success code (see section 2). The `.1` after it means it's an address status (also section 2), the whole `*.1.5` pattern is listed in section 3.2. Not all combinations of prefix and status make sense - for example 5.1.7 makes sense for rejection by a spam filter, but there isn't really any meaning to 2.1.7 for being accepted by a spam filter!

Comment: You could try setting `$mail->SingleTo = true;` and it will send each message separately (if you set multiple 'to' addresses), which might give you a little more precise feedback. You could also try turning on/off `SMTPKeepAlive`. Unless you're sending large volumes (thousands), adding delays probably won't help.

Comment: Well I got round it by changing the code. Whereas I used to have this at the top of each function $mail->IsSMTP(); changed to $mail->IsMail(); -- Also added some extra code and clean up code around the sending of each emauil. $mail = new PHPMailer;$mail->IsMail();$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;$mail->Timeout = 30; [CODE] $mail->SmtpClose();$mail = null;  ----   So I now use the IsMail method instead of IsSMTP which from what I read uses FSOCK undernearth. I did try a global (one PHPMailer obj passed in globally) but this caused every1s email on the CC address (COMPLAINTS!!!) so sticking to this